# grounding homemade light fixture

Tags: grounding

I am making a light fixture with iron plumbing pipe and 18-2 lamp wire (yeah, I'm one of those people). I just want to clarify a couple of things - with the 2-strand lamp wire, the one with the ridge is the neutral, right? There is no plug to go by as I'll be hard wiring into box in the ceiling.
Also, the fixture should be grounded for safety - what is the best way to add a ground wire to the actual fixture? the one from the power supply is around the ground screw in the junction box and should be paired to one attached to the fixture itself (with a marette), shouldn't it?
Thanks for your help,
d

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put a 2-wire cap (plug) on the fixture cord and plug it in? For some reason a hard-wired home made light fixture makes me a bit nervous.

Answer (score 3):

My first suggestion would be to get 18 AWG fixture wire (TFFN/AWM) instead of lamp cord -- portable cords aren't rated for use within fixtures, and I'd cite one inside an originally permanently wired luminaire as a 400.8 violation.  As to grounding the actual fixture -- I'd use a standard conduit grounding bushing such as [this one for 1/2" pipe](http://www.homedepot.com/p/1-2-in-Rigid-Insulated-Metallic-Grounding-Bushing-2-Pack-29521/100164273?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-100123427-_-100164273-_-N) where the fixture attaches to the ceiling box (presumably through a conduit knockout faceplate).